# Extend GridView ActionColumn with additional icon

Tags: gridview, yii2

I'm building a webapp with Yii2 framework that will provide users (logged in) the capability to download pre-uploaded files by administrators.

I've created the action `actionDownload` in the specific controller that call the `sendFile()` method.

How can I create a button that call the specific action `actionDownload` on click in a GridView (the list of documents)?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to place this button? In action column with buttons like view / update / delete? Or in separate column? How the files are downloaded? In archive, separately or one file for each GridView row? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. I need to place the button in the action column. Every row in the GridView have one specific file so I need one button for each Grofview row.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Extend declaration of [template](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$template-detail) and [buttons](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$buttons-detail) like this:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{download} {view} {update} {delete}',
    'buttons' => [
        'download' => function ($url) {
            return Html::a(
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>',
                $url, 
                [
                    'title' => 'Download',
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                ]
            );
        },
    ],
],
```

The download icon with the url will be added to existing set of icons. You can see for example how default icons are rendered [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/grid/ActionColumn.php#L104).

In common case you don't even have to build link manually, it will be constructed based on the button name and model primary key, for example `/download?id=1`.

In case you want different url special property exists, it's called [$urlCreator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$urlCreator-detail), but you can also change it right in the button rendering closure, for example:

```
'download' => function ($url, $model) {
    return Html::a(
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-download"></span>',
        ['another-controller/anotner-action', 'id' => $model->id], 
        [
            'title' => 'Download',
            'data-pjax' => '0',
        ]
    );
},
```

Comment: This works well, just replace glyphicon-arrow-download by glyphicon-download to display the icon.

Answer (score 2):

How to add another action button in kartik-v yii2 grid action column?

Just see following example.I have added copy button.

```
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
    'dropdown' => false,
    'vAlign'=>'middle',
    'template' => '{delete} {view} {update} {copy}',
    'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) { 
            return Url::to([$action,'id'=>$key]);
    },
    'buttons'=>[
        'copy' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>', ['copy', 'id'=>$model->id],['title'=>'Copy']);
        },
    ],      
    'viewOptions'=>['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=>'View','data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
    'updateOptions'=>['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=>'Update', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
    'deleteOptions'=>['role'=>'modal-remote','title'=>'Delete', 
                      'data-confirm'=>false, 'data-method'=>false,// for overide yii data api
                      'data-request-method'=>'post',
                      'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
                      'data-confirm-title'=>'Are you sure?',
                      'data-confirm-message'=>'Are you sure want to delete this item'], 
],
```

Answer (score 2):

template attribute is important

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         'id', 
         'title',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'buttons' => [
                'additional_icon' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return Html::a ( '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> ', ['controller/action', 'id' => $model->id] );
                },
            ],
            'template' => '{update} {view} {delete} {additional_icon}'


        ],
    ],
]);
```