# Yii2: GridView for one-to-many relational data

Tags: php, yii2

I have an object, `Object1`, that references `Object2` in a one-to-many relationship: one `Object1` to many `Object2`.

In my `Object1` view, I am trying to include a `yii\grid\GridView` of the related `Object2` items only. Not in addition to the `Object1` data. Just a `GridView` of `Object2` items only.

Using code like that below, I believe I have to set both `$dataProvider` and `$searchModel` in my controller but I'm not sure how to link `Yii::$app->request->queryParams` with `$id`.

My code just returns all `Object2` items, regardless of their relationship with `Object1`, which although makes perfect sense to me, is not what I'm looking for.

I am not even sure that this is the correct approach. Does anyone know of a solution? Thanks in advance.

```
/* Object1 model */
public function getRelations() {
    return $this->hasMany(Object2::className(), ['relation' => 'id']);
}

/* Object1 view */
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'attr1',
        'attr2',
        'attr3',
        'attr4',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);

/* Object1 controller */
public function actionView($id){
    $searchModel = new Object2Search();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What do you want  to show in your gridview?

Comment: The attributes of `Objectt2`, whose `relation` attribute is the `id` of the `Object1` currently being viewed in the view.

Comment: every object in object1 has multiple object in object2.you can get relations and use foreach for showing them

Comment: Yes. Of course I could. But I would like to use the GridView.

Comment: you can customize gridview

Comment: Yes. There are lots of things I could do, like just write my own widget, but it makes more sense to reuse what's available. I'm sure my problem is not a unique one. It seems a pretty standard use of a GridView.

Comment: maybe this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048452/yii2-has-many-gridview-and-detailview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering GridView in detail view I can suggest alternative approach.

Create a separate regular `GridView` widgets for both `Object1` and `Object2` items.

Extend `ActionColumn` of `Object1` GridView with additional link to related items. I already explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28028556/4323648), but I also include code here for better understanding:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{objects2} {view} {update} {delete}',
    'buttons' => [
        'objects2' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
            /* @var $model common\models\Object1 */
            return Html::a(
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>',
                ['objects2/index', 'object1_id' => $model->id],
                [
                    'title' => 'Objects 2',
                    'aria-label' => 'Objects 2',
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                ]
            );
        },        
    ],
],
```

Modify `index` action of `Object2Controller` to accept additional parameter (Object 1 id):

```
/**
 * @param integer $object1_id
 * @return string
 * @throws \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function actionIndex($object1_id)
{
    $searchModel = new Object2Search;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

`search()` method of `Object2Search` should also handle additional parameter:

```
/**
 * @param array $params
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Object2::find()->where(['object1_id' => $params['object1_id']]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,            
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // Additional filters

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Make sure to not include `object1_id` in `rules()` and additional filters.

As for display of `Object2` items, simply exclude `object1_id` column and you are done.

Obviously this can be customized more, it's just a basic example.

The main advantage of this approach is code for models of different type is separated and easier to maintain.

As for using it in detail view, modify `search()` method of `Object2Search` model to apply initial filter by `object1_id` as I described above, but in this case pass `id` parameter from query params (which comes from `view` action):

```
$query = Object2::find()->where(['object1_id' => $params['id']]);
```

Use partials for `GridView` for better views organization.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but am I correct, that this will show all Object1data, with related data shown when the icon is clicked? This is not the question I asked.

Comment: @MrGoobri Read additional remark after explanation of this alternative. You just need to apply initial filter by object 1 id.

Comment: You are correct, the small code snippet you provide at the bottom does work for this instance, yes, but consequentially it will then break the `Object2` index view, where I see all `Object2` instances?

Comment: @MrGoobri How it will break the index view?

Comment: Sorry - if my `Object2` index view were to contain a list of all `Object2`, it will throw an exception as it won't recognise `$params['id']`: `Undefined index: id`. I could put an `if` in there to catch this but this would now be the `id` of `Object2` not `Object1`. Am I correct?

Comment: I think I am wrong. Sorry. And you are right. Thank you for your help. :)